# Using intent to go back previous page instead go in to the previous page...

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using intent go back to the previous page and put `finish();` But It goes like **B page go in A page** instead of **B page back to A page**. Do I type wrong code?

**Here is the code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Donation_Page.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

Comment: you want your previous activity not to update when you go back ?

Comment: you can simply finish this activity

Comment: use only `finish()`

Comment: Ya. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change your code from**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Donation_Page.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

**to**

```
   finish();
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

you can also try **@Override onBackPressed** to go back to previous Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```